# Possible to add current directory to CLASSPATH variable permanently in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I would like to know if there is any way to add something to the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable through Windows "system properties" which will make the "current directory", that is the directory in which one is when calling a function or class from the command prompt, a permanent part of this path.

Comment: Yes. There is. However, that's not programming - it's system configuration and offtopic for this site.

Comment: @Kajsa - try the super user stack: http://superuser.com/tour

Comment: OK. I'll move the question there.

Answer (score 0):

@Kajsa- The current directory is in classpath by default(unless you explicitly set that to other value).
Confirm by doing System.out.print(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
If you want to set 'classpath' variable then append it with .; so that current directory stays in classpath.

Comment: Hey. I already tried this but it does not work. When I run a java file i need to add it to the `java`command every time.

Answer (score 0):

@Kajsa- Simply follow the steps below to find out what is the issue.

1. Did you make sure that changes in system environment variables are reflecting to the newly opened command prompt(you may have to logoff and re-login in your system that depends on your system settings). Use the command 'echo %variable_name%'(assuming u r using windows) to confirm the changes.
2. Once you are sure about this then, remove(delete) the classpath variable from system environment, follow the same process to verify about your change in classpath variable. This time the command: echo %classpath% will simply print '%classpath%'(without quotes). This means classpath environment variable is removed. If the above command prints something else that means removal of classpath environment variable is not reflected.
3. After verifying that classpath variable is removed. Now run the below code snippet(you should be able to run safely wihout any compilation errors). What does this print? It should simply print dot(.) character(I have tested on Windows 8).

   class C
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           System.out.print(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
       }
   }

This means when there is no classpath variable defined, the jvm assigns the default value of classpath to the current directory.

4. If you see something other than dot(.) character that means you have already changed classpath system environment variable to some other value. And hence you are facing problems in running java command.
5. To overcome this situation you have to append the current classpath variable value with dot(.) character. For e.g. if the current value of classpath is 'C:\Users\Kajsa\Desktop\dirA' then you change its value as 'C:\Users\Kajsa\Desktop\dirA;.;' so that dirA as well as the current directory(from which you are executing java command) both are in classpath and the required class files will be searched accordingly. You can add as many directories as you wish(separated with ;). Doing this you don't have to use java -cp everytime.

I hope this solves your problem.